# Retrieve the Image location for photo using Graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Graph API we can access the image for any object like a user, event, photo etc. if its ID is provided.

So if I need to retrieve my user profile pic 
I can do it by

https://graph.facebook.com/100000109274242/picture

My ID is 100000109274242

The above URL redirects me to https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/49592_100000109274242_1437093998_q.jpg

Which is the actual URL of my image.
I need to write a JS function using which I need to retrieve the actual URL of the photo.
I couldnt do anything because I dont understand where to start from using JS.

Answer (score 1):

- First of all load and initialize Facebook JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/
  (section Loading)
- You should interact with FB api only when JS SDK initialized. Here is an example off call:

  ```
              FB.api(100000109274242+'/picture',function(userImage){
                  alert(userImage);
              });
  ```

**UPD**
Full example. HTML:

```
<div id="fb-root">
  <!-- you must include this div for the JS SDK to load properly -->
</div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    FB.api(100000109274242+'/picture',function(userImage){
         alert(userImage);
    });
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: I have about 20 IDS of users on the same page ! Can I retrieve all of them by changing the value of ID in the above code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display the image you can simply use the first link directly:

```
<img src="https://graph.facebook.com/100000109274242/picture">
```

Since this is a 302 redirect, the browser will handle it and show the final picture without a need for you to resolve it with JS. I'm not sure if you really wanted the url in your JS or you figured you needed to resolve it.

BTW, in case you are interested, here's the header response for that url, it sends back a type of jpeg and a redirect to the actual graphic.

```
curl --HEAD https://graph.facebook.com/100000109274242/picture
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
...
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Location: https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/49592_100000109274242_1437093998_q.jpg
...
```

Comment: Actually I was looking to place this response in an Lightbox since my lightbox doesnt handle the 302 response I need to give the exact location of the image to show it !